# Akka Remote - Prevent listener side disassociation

Tags: akka, akka-remoting

Let's say we have A and B, configured remote (netty.udp) (no cluster). Both started on different ports. Actor in A sends messages to actors in B through routing (using RemoteRouterConfig and by address). They all get it and reply. When the work is done A is terminated. After sometime B logs a disassociation message.

`No response from remote. Transport failure detector triggered. (internal state was Open)
Association with remote system [akka.udp://folder@127.0.0.1:2552] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]`

If we again start A and try to send messages to B actors, messages do not get any replies. Is there a way to prevent that disassociation? Or a way to connect again when A starts?

Comment: Is your router routing to a pool or a group?

Comment: It is a pool @StefanoBonetti roundrobinpool..